# Cassandra failure during read query

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I have a Cassandra Table with ~500 columns and primary key `((userId, version, shredId), rowId)` where `shredId` is used to distribute data evenly into different partitions. Table also has a default TTL of 2 days to expire data as data are for real-time aggregation. The compaction strategy is TimeWindowCompactionStrategy.

The workflow is:

1. write data to input table (with consistency EACH_QUORUM)
2. Run spark aggregation (on rows with same the `userId` and `version`)
3. write aggregated data to output table.

But I'm getting `Cassandra failure during read query` when size of data gets large; more specifically, once there are more than 210 rows in one partition, read queries fail.

How can I tune my database and change properties to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After investigation and research, the issued is caused by null values been inserted for some empty column. this creates large amount of tombstones and eventually timeout the query.